# Which is the best shared configuration between NodeJS and Shellscript?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, config

I need to share some configuration variables between a script built in NodeJS and a Shellscript.
This configuration variables contain data like error codes, urls, folders...

First adopted approach was .env file, but I feel it is not the right place to store this type of information. What would you recommend? Maybe a json file, easy to read with `fs` and `JSON` in NodeJS and with `jq` processor in Shellscript?

Other ideas?

Comment: a `.env` file is actually not such a bad option, related: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv (check out the popularity of this package!)

Comment: .env + dotenv is my current setup, but I see .env more for username, passwords, tokens, secrets, indeed URLs but not really error codes, or folders. Anyway let's see if someone has other suggestions, thanks anyway

Comment: Indeed it sounds weird to have error-codes in a config because they should be env-agnostic so something like an enum would be more appropriate. But folders/URLs are something that could change between envs so config is a good place to have it. Usually there's a config service that sets up the project which takes its initial setup either from files or DB and these values can be overriden by environment variables.